# Error using SET together with SELECT using MariaDB

Tags: php, sql, mariadb

Using PHP and SQL, I want to create a table row number on the fly using a user defined variable in but I get the following error:

Invalid query: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT...

I have tested the SQL code using phpMyadmin at my web hotel without any problem.

Here is the php/SQL code stripped down to a minimum:

```
$sql = "SET @i=-1; SELECT @i:=@i+1 as rownum FROM my_table";
$res = mysql_query($sql);

if (!$res) {
    die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
}
```

What am I missing?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not run multiple queries in one statement. But you can do a variable initialization inside the query.

```
$sql = "SELECT @i:=@i+1 as rownum FROM my_table, (SELECT @i := -1) var_init";
```